# Getting a user's Twitter home feed without authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, twitter

I am coding an application which I get a user's profile timeline and user's friends' twitter updates (home feed). I am using Rails and Koala gem.

I can get the user's own twitter updates without authentication but I can't get the user's friends' updates (aka, home feed) without authentication.

I searched Twitter api but api functions that I can use (statuses/home_timeline, statuses/friends_timeline) require authentication.

Is there a way to get friends' updates without authentication? (only updates of public accounts).

I am considering to 1) first getting friend list of a person 2) then getting their public timeline feed and 3) creating a seperate feed. But I want to ask here about the possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to directly get a users home_timeline without authenticating as them. Your only option is going to get all the friends user_timelines and combine them into a single timeline.